# When should a confirmation email be sent after placing an order?

Tags: email

With regards an OMS, what is the best method to send a confirmation email? The 2 options I have so far are;

1. A script on the order page sends an email once the record is written to the database.
2. A scheduled task on the server, send the email, polling the database every-so-often to find new entries.

Which method do systems currently use?

Comment: Please can you explain why it's not constructive? I'd try to update the question if I knew what was wrong with it.

Comment: "OMS" being.... what? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMS

Comment: I took it to mean Order Management System. I may of course be wrong.

Comment: @Digbyswift is right, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_management_system.

Comment: Good to be thinking about scalability rather than just taking the quick approach (1) that many systems often take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question of scalability. Sending a confirmation email once the record is written to the database is the least scalable. The more orders that are taken , the more emails are sent potentially tying up resources.

A scheduled task is certainly better as emails can be queued up and can be sent in a separate process.

A further option which you could consider is using neither and delegating the responsibility of sending emails to a 3rd party dedicated emailing service, i.e. via an API. This is much better since your hosting does not have to consider the load and you can utilise any reporting offered by the 3rd party. Plus many services offer a free quota up to a certain threshold. This will allow you OMS and business to scale appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

For e-commerce websites, it might be better to think about the best user experience.

Given that, you would want to send the email as soon as the order is received so the user knows that they have purchased the item. The sooner it gets into their inbox, the sooner they will be happy that they have made their purchase.

I agree with Digbyswift that sending the confirmation email once the record is written to the database is the least scalable. But I would argue that if your system has gotten to the point that you are taking so many orders that your system cannot keep up, you have a wonderful problem on your hands that you now probably have resources to handle.

At [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com), we handle the emails of a few e-commerce websites, so perhaps you would benefit from an arrangement with an email service provider to off-load this task so that all of your resources can be spent on keeping your site up and your databases running.

Here are some great alternatives if PostageApp is not your style:

- [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com)
- [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com)
- [Mailjet](http://mailjet.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you apply a message based architecture; you could just publish an order created message and have any number of subscribers respond to that event.  You could create a listener that sends the email in house (bespoke option) or another listener that called the API of a 3rd party emailer to send the email on your behalf (as per @Digbyswift)

What I've always liked about this approach is

1. You can have any number of listeners live at any one time.
2. You can create a new listener and change how you send the email without needing to change/redeploy the OMS application itself.
3. You can take the listener(s) off line and stop / delay the sending of the email without losing any notifications or affecting the OMS itself.